# Having trouble installing/using xmlhttprequest

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, node-red

I am taking my first steps in node.js/node-RED and need to do http requests (GET, POST with and without xml payload) from a node component so I figured that [xmlhttprequest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest) is my best option. I have npm-installed it. Actually installed it in ~/.node-red/node_modules and /usr/local/lib/node_modules but each time I launch node-RED it does not activate my node component with the following error:

```
Welcome to Node-RED
===================

7 Aug 09:05:20 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.17.5
7 Aug 09:05:20 - [info] Node.js  version: v6.11.2
7 Aug 09:05:20 - [info] Darwin 16.7.0 x64 LE
7 Aug 09:05:20 - [info] Loading palette nodes
7 Aug 09:05:21 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
7 Aug 09:05:21 - [warn] [rpi-gpio] Info : Ignoring Raspberry Pi specific node
7 Aug 09:05:21 - [warn] [synaptiq-solar] Error: Cannot find module 'xmlhttprequest'
7 Aug 09:05:21 - [warn] ------------------------------------------------------
7 Aug 09:05:21 - [info] Settings file  : /Users/rudi/.node-red/settings.js
7 Aug 09:05:21 - [info] User directory : /Users/rudi/.node-red
7 Aug 09:05:21 - [info] Flows file     : /Users/rudi/.node-red/flows_Rudi.local.json
7 Aug 09:05:21 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
7 Aug 09:05:21 - [info] Waiting for missing types to be registered:
7 Aug 09:05:21 - [info]  - synaptiq-solar
```

The name of my component is synaptiq-solar and its code starts with requiring the xmlhttprequest component like this:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```

Also, my package.json has a dependency section referring to xmlhttprequest as you can see below:

```
{
  "name": "synaptiq-solar",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Just playing around, learning how to create a custom node",
  "dependencies": {
    "xmlhttprequest": "1.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "node-red": {
    "nodes": {
      "synaptiq-solar": "synaptiq-solar.js"
    }
  },
  "author": "Smappee n.v.",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

So what am I doing wrong? Should I install the xmlhttprequest component in some other location? Is there another lib directory that node-RED is looking to find dependend components?

Comment: I may be a bit lost on the whole Node RED situation... but `XMLHttpRequest` is part of the Living Standard of JavaScript. Why would you need to install it..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a custom node has an external dependency, it should declare it within its `package.json` file so that they get installed alongside your custom module.

If you have created this as a "local" node (with just a `.js` and `.html` file in the `nodes` directory and no `package.json`), you should move over to creating it as a module.

The documentation includes a guide on properly packaging your node: https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/packaging

Comment: I did read that section and that is why I have added a dependency section in my package.json. I realize that I should have added that to my original question so I have edited that and also ran npm update. The latter seems to bundle xmlhttprequest inside my node though and that's not what I want once I release the component is it?

Comment: I did all of the instruction again (i.e. sudo npm link in local directory and npm  link synaptiq-solar in my ~/.node-red directory and now it seems to work so thanks for bring that back to my attention.

Comment: glad you got it working. Adding it to your package.json will not bundle the dependency inside your node - but it tells npm that it needs to install that module as a dependency when it installs your node. If my answer helped resolve your question, please remember to mark it as Accepted.

Comment: So you are saying that I should not have had to do npm update. Ok, so when I undo the effects of that (i.e. remove the nod_modules subdirectory) and then the two packaging instructions, my component indeed still works. Great!